# Very slow UI when running nvidia graphics card Ubuntu 22

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

So I've been wanting to get my graphics card working properly on my laptop. I have an Nvidia RTX Quadro 3000 Max-Q. I've been trying to get it to work for some time now. Whenever I have the driver installed, either the card isn't used as I expect--or it is, and I get about 10fps on all UI. This includes animations, mouse movement, keystrokes, etc.. Here's what I've tried and their results:

- On Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04 x11, I tried dang near every nvidia driver between 470 and 550. 10fps incurs
- On Ubuntu 22.04.4 Wayland, (given my laptop boots correctly) the graphics card simply isn't used and my intel graphics are used despite ensuring that my prime-selection is set nvidia (aka performance mode). Better than 10fps, but not the performance solution I'm looking for because it's still the cpu doing the work.

Was wondering if anyone else has had this issue of 10fps when using nvidia drivers on x11. Any direction or resources helpful :)

Comment: Lots of people advise to disable secure boot in the BIOS to an Nvidia driver work. ...not sure if you've tried that or not.

Comment: Please add the output of xrandr --listproviders to your original posting. Sometimes the source/sink get reversed, but can be switched with environment variables. e.g.  __NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia <progtorun>